# Host on Google Docs or use Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs, web-hosting

**Intro:**
Hello, i am in a little doubt. I have a blogger site and i create small apps using HTML and host them elsewhere and show it on my main site using iframes. 
**Problem:**
Now i can use Google Docs to host these HTML files or even i can use Google App Engine to host them. Both are free. What i do is use google drive program to update any HTML file i edit, lets say i want to edit a file, i will edit on my computer and fire up google drive program and updated version will be hosted. I can do the same with google app engine 
**Question:**
Which i should choose? I mean based on allowed bandwidth etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better, use GCS (Google cloud storage) configured to serve static files as a website:

> The Website Configuration feature enables you to configure a Google
>   Cloud Storage bucket to simulate the behavior of a static website. You
>   can define main pages or directory indices (for example, index.html)
>   for buckets and "directories". Also, you can define a custom error
>   page in case a requested resource does not exist.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

Then to update it's just to copy the files into the bucket with a command line tool or browser based interface.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i have now started using google cloud storage. It does require a credit or debit card as opposed to google Docs method, but it is still free and seems solid